# Errores en php para crear mapa de google vinculado a base de datos

Tags: php

El programa es el siguiente:

```
<?php
require("phpsqlajax_dbinfo.php");

function parseToXML($htmlStr)
{
$xmlStr=str_replace('<','&lt;',$htmlStr);
$xmlStr=str_replace('>','&gt;',$xmlStr);
$xmlStr=str_replace('"','&quot;',$xmlStr);
$xmlStr=str_replace("'",'&#39;',$xmlStr);
$xmlStr=str_replace("&",'&amp;',$xmlStr);
return $xmlStr;
}

// Opens a connection to a MySQL server
$connection=mysqli_connect ('localhost', $username, $password);
if (!$connection) {
  die('Not connected : ' . mysqli_error());
}

// Set the active MySQL database
$db_selected = mysqli_select_db($connection, $database);
if (!$db_selected) {
  die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysqli_error());
}

// Select all the rows in the markers table
$query = "SELECT * FROM markers WHERE 1";
$result = mysqli_query($query);
if (!$result) {
  die('Invalid query: ' . mysqli_error());
}

header("Content-type: text/xml");

// Start XML file, echo parent node
echo "<?xml version='1.0' ?>";
echo '<markers>';
$ind=0;
// Iterate through the rows, printing XML nodes for each
while ($row = @mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
  // Add to XML document node
  echo '<marker ';
  echo 'id="' . $row['id'] . '" ';
  echo 'name="' . parseToXML($row['name']) . '" ';
  echo 'address="' . parseToXML($row['address']) . '" ';
  echo 'lat="' . $row['lat'] . '" ';
  echo 'lng="' . $row['lng'] . '" ';
  echo 'type="' . $row['type'] . '" ';
  echo '/>';
  $ind = $ind + 1;
}

// End XML file
echo '</markers>';

?>
```

Me da los siguientes errores:

```
Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /storage/ssd2/594/12253594/public_html/mapa.php on line 28

Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in /storage/ssd2/594/12253594/public_html/mapa.php on line 30
Invalid query:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las advertencias son claras:

- *`mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given`*

Te indica que `mysqli_query()` necesita dos parámetros que son: 1º la conexión; 2º la consulta a ejecutar. Tú le estás pasando solamente uno.

- *`mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given`*

Te indica que `mysqli_error()`está esperando un parámetro, que es la conexión, pero no lo estás pasando ninguno.

Para resolver ambos problemas:

Donde quiera que uses `mysqli_query` debes ponerlo así:

```
mysqli_query($connection,$query);
```

Y donde quiera que uses `mysqli_error`:

```
mysqli_error($connection);
```

## Advertencia sobre malas prácticas y prácticas obsoletas

En tu código se aprecian malas prácticas que consisten en el uso de `die()` sin compasión y en silenciar posibles errores con `@`. Convendría que lo evites, tomando en mano el control de tu código para emitir mensajes o redirigir en caso de fallos. Silenciar los errores o delegar en `die()` puede llevar a comportamientos inesperados.

En la nueva API `mysqli` le puedes pasar como 4º parámetro la base de datos a la que quieres conectar, por tanto te puedes ahorrar esta parte:

```
// Set the active MySQL database
$db_selected = mysqli_select_db($connection, $database);
if (!$db_selected) {
  die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysqli_error());
}
```

Creando la conexión así:

```
$connection=mysqli_connect ('localhost', $username, $password, $database);
```

`mysqli_select_db()` sólo es útil si estás conectado a una BD y quieres cambiar a otra.